# Lots of redundant messages "Warning: painting PicturePile without content!"

Tags: android, css, html, android-webview

We are building an application which loads URL in a Webview , in that I am loading HTML5 function that create animated icons like [this][1], everything works as expected above android OS 4.4 but in OS 4.2 it's not showing me any data in webview and redundant logging output from application. A lot of "Warning: painting PicturePile without content!"

Environment:
Device: Samsung Duos
OS: 4.2.2

Thanks in advance.

```
 [1]: http://codepen.io/joshbader/pen/EjXgqr
```